# change button border color when the button is being clicked and after

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

What to do to change navbar-toggle button behaviour when the button is being clicked and after?
It gets some blue border color.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be this, bootstrap has some automatic styling for `.navbar-toggle`. You can add something like below to counteract it's default styling.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
    border:none;
}


.btn.active.focus, .btn.active:focus, .btn.focus, .btn:active.focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, It seems there is some default styling. Your code works but doesn't counteract this default behaviour. Default blue border still exists around new border color. The right question should be: How to change default bootstrap styling for this button? I tried via botstrap.min.css but without success.

Comment: Oh, then you must be talking about the blue glow border for buttons. I updated my answer accordingly. If you need it just specifically for the `.navbar-toggle` then you can change it to `.navbar-toggle.btn.active` and so on. The blue glow is a default for chrome around buttons and inputs. Helpful for people not using a mouse to navigate and just using a keyboard. But if you want to get rid of it, then use the above. Add an `!important` after if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar button {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how your button is being displayed when it has a `class="navbar-toggle"` but I think what you need is something like :

```
$('button.navbar-toggle').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid blue');
});
```

If you wish to not use jQuery, you can do :

```
document.querySelector('button.navbar-toggle').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.target.style.border = '1px solid blue';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try css:
`[your-btn] {out-line: none;}`